# ClassifierMeasurements returns strange errors

Tags: image-processing, warning-messages, machine-learning

I am following the example listed on this page [ResNet 50](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/ResNet-50-Trained-on-ImageNet-Competition-Data/) to train a custom classifier and inspect the outcome with ClassifierMeasurements. My training set has 443 images from more than 30 classes. The training with NetTrain progresses smoothly and results in a NetTrainResultsObject. When I try to call in the trained net with ClassifierMeasurements to compute accuracy the code returns a lot of errors.

```
ClassifierMeasurements[trainedNetIncV1["TrainedNet"], testingSet, "Accuracy"]
```

[image: errors returned in the notebook]

I am using v 12.2.0 on a linux box with GPU. This code has worked in the past with v12.1. PacletInstall["NeuralNetworks"] reports that I am running v 12.2.14 which seems to be the latest. I am not sure if something has changed between the versions specific to this task. I appreciate any help that can be provided.

Thank you

Comment: You may need to ask WRI support about this - the function appears to work fine on my machine. Perhaps running `PacletInstall["NeuralNetworks"]` might update the version on your machine to the latest version?

Comment: Thanks! I checked the version with PacletInstall and it reports the latest version is already installed (12.2.14). I will reach out to them as well.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that this issue is known to WRI. From their technical support,

"ClassifierMeasurements is giving these messages when the MeanCrossEntropy is divergent. A simpler example that exhibits similar behavior is:"

```
ClassifierMeasurements[{<|"A" -> 0.9, "B" -> 0.1|>, <|"A" -> 0.8, "B" ->
0.2|>, <|"A" -> 0.2, "B" -> 0.8|>, <|"A" -> 0.6, "B" -> 0.4|>}, 
Table[RandomImage[], 4],"MeanCrossEntropy"]
```

I am closing this question and keeping this message here in case it helps someone else.